# C# if and console not working well

Tags: c#, console-application

This program doesn't work well. The output is always:
You can drink alcohol!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Superif
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int age;
            string result; 

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age!");
            age = Console.Read();

            if (age >= 18)
            {
                result = "You can drink alcohol!";
            }
            else
            {
                result = "You can't drink alcohol!";
            }


            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `if` statements not working well. I suggest you print out the value of `age`... I'm pretty sure it won't be what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong method. `Console.Read` my [MDSN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Reads the next character from the standard input stream.

If you for instance input `"18"` and check the value of `age` you will see it has `49` which is the ASCII value of the `"1"`.

Use `Console.ReadLine()` instead which reads the entire string line and then parse it into an `int`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int age;
    string result;

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age!");
    if(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out age))
    {
        result = "Invalid Input";
    }
    else if (age >= 18)
    {
        result = "You can drink alcohol!";
    }
    else
    {
        result = "You can't drink alcohol!";
    }

    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

*Also notice that I decided to use `int.TryParse` rather than `int.Parse` to avoid exceptions of invalid cast*

Comment: Just posted but you are first :).

Answer (score 3):

Because `Console.Read()` will give you ASCII value not the integer value. so you should try `Console.ReadLine()`.

```
    int age;
    string result;

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age!");
    age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    if (age >= 18)
    {
        result = "You can drink alcohol!";
    }
    else
    {
        result = "You can't drink alcohol!";
    }


    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadKey();
```